# Injecting G-Sensor, Accelerometer or Gyroscope Events to running Apps

Tags: android, accelerometer, gyroscope, motionevent

I have again a question where I am stuck at. Seems like the possibilities with Android aren't so "endless".
My app (systemsigned) is now able to inject KeyEvents and PointerSyncs - using Instrumentation API - to the currently focused app. Now I want the same for a gyroscope, gravity-sensor or a accelerometer. Is it possible to inject those events programmatically? [Without (su) shell if possible]

Thank you!

Comment: Did you find an answer for injecting sensor events programmitically?

Comment: No unfortunately not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that it is not possible by default Android API!

But what you could do is to modify the sensor unix buffer that is somewhere stored in a file. However this requieres Root & SU access.

Comment: Hello, can you please explain how to modify the sensor unix buffer so that i can emulate the magnetic-field sensor ?